# Как расположить в MatLab на графике точки в местах целых значений

Tags: математика, matlab, график

Имеется определённая функция, решённая в матлабе. Необходимо построить график, а на нём расположить точки только в местах, где значение целое, а не дробное.

Если кому интересна конкретика, то функция имеет вид:

```
y = abs((cos(n).^sin(m-3)) + log(sqrt(2)+ 0.2*n + m^2.4) - 3 - (n+2)/(m-3.2))
```

где `n = (-20:0.1:20)`, а `m = 16`

Строится график `y(n)`

Так как шаг 0.1, то в построенном графике мы имеем множество дробных значений. Если выполнить, к примеру, команду `plot(n,y,':B',n,y,'SM')`, то точками обозначатся просто все значения n.

Вот в том и вопрос: как сделать, чтобы отметились только целые значения?

Comment: clear;clc
n=(-20:0.1:20); m=16;
y=@(n) abs(((cos(n)).^(sin(m-3)))+(log((sqrt(2))+(0.2*n)+(m^2.4)))-3-((n+2)/(m-3.2)));
n1=round(n);
plot(n,y(n),'b',n1,y(n1),'+r','LineWidth',2)
grid

вот верное и простое решение моей проблемы :)

Comment: простое и неверное, почему ответил в комменте к своему ответу

Answer (score 1):

Самое просто решение в лоб - просто посчитать функцию еще раз для n1 = -20:20 (только целых значений) и ее построить. Или выбрать только целые значения и их построить, если не ошибаюсь можно примерно так:

```
intN = isinteger(n); % массив булевных значений является ли n(i) целым 
n1 = n(intN);
y1 = y(intN);
```

Но нужно проверять - у меня нет под рукой матлаба чтобы проверить правильность решения. Минус второго решения - если вы как-нибудь сделаете шаг, например, 0.3 то график будет пропускать многие целые (хотя тут вопрос дискретная ли у вас функция или нет). Можно ли как-то именно плот заставить подсвечивать только целые - не знаю

Comment: Спасибо, не знаю правильно ли это но решил сделать просто
u=round(n)
то есть обьявил просто новую переменную которая соответствует целым значениям в векторе n

Comment: точно неправильно, такой вариант наплодит лишних точек, например, если n=[0 0.25, 0.5 0.75 1], то итоговое значение вполне может получиться [0 0 1 1 1]

Answer (score 1):

```
plot(round (n),y,':B',n,y,'SM')
```

Comment: Не стоит давать просто ответы с кодом. Постарайтесь своими словами объяснить, что делает приведенный вами код.

Comment: Пожалуйста, пишите более развёрнутые ответы. Дополните ваш ответ объяснением кода или опишите ваши действия.